# Integrated coverage using scoverage for scala code and test cases written in python

Tags: scala, scoverage

I am trying to get test coverage for Scala project.

1.Test cases are written in python. 
2.Need to run multiple test cases at same time and finally get coverage report. Its like integrated test coverage.

Referring https://github.com/scoverage/sbt-scoverage for scoverage. Any suggestion how can I execute it?

Comment: Did you ever find a solution for this? I am attempting the very same thing now and I am running into a lot of problems